# Not able to use local variables in Sitecore Edit Frames

Tags: sitecore-client

@Edited after [Mark's](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/73/mark-cassidy) answer.

I have a ascx control where I have defined some variables.

```
<%
var showFilters = RenderingParameters.ShowFilters;
var minimizeCardHeight = RenderingParameters.MinimizeCardHeight;
var numberOfProfiles = 0;
%>
<sc:EditFrame ID="editContributors" runat="server" Title="Contributors Area" Buttons="/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Test Button">
<div class='test'>
<% if(minimizeCardHeight) { %> 
<div class="divider"></div>
<% } %>
</div>
</sc:EditFrame>
```

Now, in visual studio there is no error shown for any variables but when I publish the code and run the page in Experience Editor, a compilation error is thrown

> CS0103: The name 'minimizeCardHeight' does not exist in the current
>   context

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of things.

1. You cannot have the `<%=` inside the `<sc:EditFrame>` control. It will not be evaluated. `<%=` sends its output to the `output stream`, it does not act as a variable as you seem to assume. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370201/why-will-expressions-as-property-values-on-a-server-controls-lead-to-a-co
2. You cannot edit Rendering Parameters using an Edit Frame. See [Inline editing of rendering parameters in Experience Editor](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/inline-editing-of-rendering-parameters-in-experience-editor) for details.

Comment: thanks, I understood that <%= %> is like response.write and will not work for variables like I'm thinking it would.
I am not able to fetch the variables even when I am not using <%= %>. I will update my code to show what I'm trying to say.